# How to Save Modal Popup values in Main Page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I am trying to save the data which is entered in the modal popup to the main page.
    here is the code for the main page.

        
            
                Company Info

```
                <div id="AddMoreDetails">
                    <div class="table" runat="server" id="AddMore">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <table style="width:200%;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Company Name</td>
                                            <td>Company Address</td>
                                            <td>Contact</td>
                                            <td>Company HO</td>
                                            <td>HO Contact</td>
                                            <td>Email ID</td>

                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <textarea id="TextArea1"></textarea>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <textarea id="TextArea2"></textarea>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <textarea id="TextArea3"></textarea>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <textarea id="TextArea4"></textarea>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <textarea id="TextArea5"></textarea>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <textarea id="TextArea6"></textarea>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: right">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
```

Here is the code for **Modal popup window**

```
<div id="myModalPopup" class="modal fade" role="dialog" data-keyboard="false"> // modal popup window
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                             <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: orangered; border-top-left-radius: 4px; border-top-right-radius: 4px;">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Company Details</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" class="tab-pane">
                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblNmeComp" Text="Name of Company" AssociatedControlID="txtNmeComp" CssClass="control-label" />
                                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNmeComp" CssClass="form-control" />
                                                    <br />
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAdrComp" Text="Adress of Company" AssociatedControlID="txtAdrComp" CssClass="control-label" />
                                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtAdrComp" CssClass="form-control" />
                                                    <br />
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblConctComp" Text="Contact Number" AssociatedControlID="txtConctComp" CssClass="control-label" />
                                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtConctComp" CssClass="form-control" />
                                                    <br />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

Here is the **button code** for **opening Modal popup window**

```
                            <button id="AddMore_Button" class="btn btn-primary" data-target="myModalPopup">Add More</button>   </div>

Here is the button code for saving data from modal popup window.

<button type="button" runat="server" onclick="savepopupdata()">
```

To get the values from modal popup window I have written a javascript function.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> //Java script function
        function savepopupdata()
        {
            document.getElementById.valueOf(txtNmeComp) = document.getElementById.valueOf(TextArea1);
            document.getElementById.valueOf(txtAdrComp) = document.getElementById.valueOf(TextArea2);
            document.getElementById.valueOf(txtConctComp) = document.getElementById.valueOf(TextArea3);

        }
    </script>
```

But unfortunately it is not saving the data. Any wrong in this code.

Comment: You need to make a copy of whole table row, and add it as a new row. I would use some kind of framework like angular for that

Comment: I see that you are using ASP.NET, you could use a `repeater` on the server side

Answer (score 1):

We can get input elements values by it attributes only like ID, Class ... 
try with

```
document.getElementById("TextArea1").value;
```

...

Comment: Also, be aware to set on web.config or the items itself ClientIdMode="Static" in order to set the correct ID to the item and not the AutoID generated on ASP

Comment: document.getElementById("txtNmeComp").value = document.getElementById("TextArea1").value;                                                               Is this correct..??

Comment: document.getElementById("txtNmeComp").value = document.getElementById("TextArea1").value , look like right.

Comment: @achyuth401 This is not what OP is looking for. He wants to add a table row

Comment: #fahadash Exactly sir

Comment: @fahadash I am trying to say The "valueOf()" method not useful to get the values form input elements

Comment: it is not triggering the action

Answer (score 0):

if you want to find elements by ids  and change their values, then  try this code

```
function savepopupdata() { 
    document.getElementById('txtNmeComp').value = document.getElementById('TextArea1').value;
    document.getElementById('txtAdrComp').value = document.getElementById('TextArea2').value; 
    document.getElementById('txtConctComp').value = document.getElementById('TextArea3').value;
}
```

Comment: this js function should trigger any events

Comment: it should trigger,but unfortunately not triggering the logic

Comment: By using above syntax, if I keep alert function before first line it is triggering. But the piece of code is not triggering